# How to know the end of process in recursion function javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I have function recursive javascript like this

```
var get_children_copy=function(file_id,current_parent,req,res){
    copyFileOrFolder(file_id,current_parent,req,res,function(id_created){
        Files.count({
            where:[
                "parent = ?",
                file_id
            ]
        }).then(function(number){
            if(number>0){
                Files.findAll({
                    where:{
                        parent:file_id
                    },
                }).then(function(data_child){
                    data_child.forEach(function(d){
                        get_children_copy(d.id,id_created,req,res);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And then I have trigger like this in my function

```
 file_to_copy_arr.forEach(function(file_id){
        get_children_copy(file_id,current_parent,req,res);
        if(file_id==file_to_copy_arr[file_to_copy_arr.length-1]){
            LogHelpers.log("copy",JSON.stringify(file_to_copy_arr),req.session.user_id);
            res.json({
                message:res.__("File has been succesfully copied"),
                data:null,
                status:"success",
                title:res.__("Information")
            });
        }
    });
```

I'm still in new in javascript using promise or callback in javascript. What I want to do is how can I Call

```
if(file_id==file_to_copy_arr[file_to_copy_arr.length-1]){
```

After all recursive function has been completed? I have to run this function after all process in `get_children_copy` finished

Comment: calling `return` will cause a function to stop returning. normally it would be used for returning a value, but you can just use it to stop the function (everything after the `return` will not run)

Comment: that's not the problem that I got.. I want to respond client after all async call in `get_children_copy` has been finished. using callback or promise. Do you have experience with it?

Comment: is `get_children_copy` synchronous or asynchronous? - anyway see if https://jsfiddle.net/r2vcL9tw/ helps

Comment: thanks alot @JaromandaX I'm still new in javascript using async function.